# Java EE REST + xml support: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext missing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to create a little REST application that respond to request with xml. The basic configuration of my application that returns normal strings works fine.

I added the following in my pom.xml in order to add support to xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But I still have the following error when the tomcat server in eclipse loads the application:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
```

My system configuration:

```
java --version
openjdk 10.0.1 2018-04-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

eclipse Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)

tomcat 8.5
```

Comment: Sanity check: cleaned? Second sanity check: dependency:tree?

Comment: @Compass, by cleaned do you ask me if I have cleaned my "build" and redownloaded the dependencies ? If so I did it via eclipse : Maven > update project. For the dependency: tree I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: From command line, or perhaps eclipse, you can run the [dependency:tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) command to see how your dependencies are being resolved. If there is, for example, a version mismatch, or your dependencies are not being properly resolved, you will be able to see it.

Comment: @Compass, no version mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java 9, JAXB is no longer part of the JDK. [This explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/9818506) written by Andy Guibert and [this migration guide](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/) should help you to understand the situation.

Therefore *"a quick and dirty solution"* is to add `--add-modules java.xml.bind` to your compile process.

Comment: Is there a way to add `--add-modules` via eclipse directly or should I modify the eclipse.ini ?